# Need Support to finalize the Migration method to migrate a Azure SQL MI Databases from Azure Cloud-Company Account to Azure Cloud-Clients Accounts

Tags: azure, database-migration, subscription, azure-cloud-services, azure-sql-managed-instance

We are trying to Migrate Azure SQL Managed Instance Databases from Azure Cloud - Company Account to Another Cloud in Clients Accounts. Need help to choose the right migration methods to migration the Azure SQL MI Databases across subscription and different accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Export your Database to your local machine as bacpac file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export

Upload into a Blob storage and import your bacpac file into the new subscription:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell